# In Django, how to include template folder I have created with the base file named base.html on settings.py?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have been learning Django for a week, but I'm not sure how to include template folder I have created with the base file named base.html on settings.py file.
In order to do that, I have changed settings.py file at the end of the code as follows.

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    BASE_DIR + '/templates/'
)
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader', 
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

In settings.py file, there is already **TEMPLATES** looks like as follows.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},]
```

When I run **python manage.py runserver**, the exception occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
...
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 108, in __init__
    "Please fix your settings." % setting)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The TEMPLATE_DIRS setting must be a tuple. Please fix your settings.
```

I think that **TEMPLATES** include **TEMPLATE_DIRS** & **TEMPLATE_LOADERS**. BUT I'm not sure.
How can I handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation suggests placing your template directories in TEMPLATES DIRS

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        BASE_DIR + '/templates/'
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},]
```

You should also use `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` to get your template path.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES

Comment: Thanks for your help. I use 1.8.7 version. I have seen that above version is 1.11. Does the code above works well when I use django 1.8.7 version?

Comment: The 1.8 docs suggest this is correct as well
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES
The change appears to have been introduced in 1.8 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/upgrading/

Comment: Thanks. What about TEMPLATE_LOADERS? As a matter of fact, I don't understand what the TEMPLATE_LOADERS means.

Comment: They are classes that determine how Django searches for template files, for example if you specify a path in DIRS, it will first check there, then it will check in an apps templates directory

Comment: Would you tell me where the TEMPLATE_LOADER is located, in TEMPLATES or out of TEMPLATES?

Comment: If you’re using the default value of TEMPLATE_LOADERS, that is, if it isn’t defined in your settings file or if it’s set to:

['django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader']

Comment: If you want to specify your own in templates in the options dictionary

'loaders': [
                # insert your TEMPLATE_LOADERS here
            ]